# When to use sum_over_time vs increase Promql Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am a little unclear on when to exactly use increase and when to use sum_over_time in order to calculate a periodic collection of data in Grafana.
I want to calculate the total percentage of availability of my system.
Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The "increase" function calculates how much a counter increased in the specified interval.

The "sum_over_time" function calculates the sum of all values in the specified interval.

Suppose you have the following data series in the specified interval:

```
5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8
```

Then you would get:

```
increase = 8-5 = 3
sum_over_time = 5+5+5+5+6+6+7+8+8+8 = 63
```

If your goal is to calculate the total percentage of availability I think it's better to use the "avg_over_time" function.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this out.

Comment: So if my use case is to find the total availability percentage of my system then would be something like this:
sum (sum_over_time(metric_name{response_code!~"2.*"}[$__range])) / sum (sum_over_time(metric_name{}[$__range]))/ * 100 ?

As I am getting some incorrect data

Comment: I think so. You just need to remove the "/" before the "* 100".

Comment: Thanks. '/' was a typing mistake here.